# Flask executes much slower than console

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a conditional performance issue I have tried everything to debug, so I thought I would share and hope. The only part of my Flask -> gunicorn -> nginx stack I am not super familiar with is Flask, so I am betting that is the center of the issue.

My app processes a bunch of PDF's into a different format. The first step of this is to check and see if the PDF has text, so as to flag it for OCR if it doesn't. This function seems to work exponentially faster from a python console than it does when executed by flask. The function that checks for text is:

```py
import textract
import time
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def write_to_log_custom(msg: str):
        with open('textract_time.txt', 'a') as log_file:
            log_file.write(msg)

    @classmethod
    def no_text(cls, file_id, server=True, **kwargs):
        try:
            this_file = File.query.filter_by(file_id=file_id).one()
            t = time.time()
            text = textract.process(this_file.get_path(absolute=True))
            msg = f"Took {time.time() - t}s to check {this_file.filename} for text using {'server' if server else 'command'}\n"
            cls.write_to_log_custom(msg)
            return True
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return False
```

This is the only function that writes to *textract_time.txt* , and after running from my service, and then from the console:

```
Took 37.51569843292236s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-152.pdf for text using server
Took 22.170623779296875s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-155.pdf for text using server
Took 14.18145203590393s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-157.pdf for text using server
----> Then from console
Took 0.18947458267211914s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-152.pdf for text using server
Took 0.20262551307678223s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-155.pdf for text using server
Took 0.3817157745361328s to check /home/ubuntu/aws/shared/Websearch/Eldredge/pdf_small/1931-July-Dec-157.pdf for text using server
```

I am confident this *textract* call is the bottle neck, based on what I can see from `top`, as well as what you can see in the log_file. Does anyone have any guidance on functions that work faster from the console than from a gunicorn thread or within a Flask app?

Thanks!

Comment: when you say slower exceution from flask. Is the request directly going to flask or nginx->gunicorn->flask

Comment: The latter. The request is made by the user on a browser which triggers the function though nginx -> gunicorn, but it's always the same function triggering the timed logging shown in the output.

Comment: How many workers and what type of workers are you using in gunicorn?

Comment: Initially I was worried it was a threading issue, so I moved it to the application execution statement, but my gunicorn initializer is:
`ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/pdf_local/.env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:pdf_local.sock -m 007 wsgi:app --threads 8`

Comment: try adding --worker-class=gevent, if this does not solve the problem I would suggest experimenting with different worker class.sync, eventlet, gevent, tornado, gthread